# How to send the post request for the below json in Restassured

Tags: rest-assured

i am new to rest assured. how to send the POST resquest for the below JSON?

```
  {
   "customer_id":"001",
   "appointment_id":"001",
   "appointment_time":"2022-10-04 00:00:00",
   "submitted_time":"2022-10-04 00:00:00",
   "first_name":"ethinic",
   "last_name":"one",
   "date_of_birth":"1910-10-10",
   "email_address":"test@gmail.com",
   "address_1":"24",
   "address_2":"testtwo",
   "postcode":"abc123",
   "phone":"1234567890",
"questions":[

      {
         "ethnicity":"Other Ethnic Groups - Chinese"
      },

      {
         "do_you_or_anyone_in_your_household_have_a_fever_a_new_persistent_cough_loss_of_taste_or_smell_or_any_other_symptoms_of_covid_19":"No"
      },
      {
         "what_is_the_main_reason_for_your_appointment_with_us":"Eye health concern"
      },
     
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible ways to send POST request with the above JSON.

1. Create POJO/DTO object that represents the same json structure and serialize it to json using library like GSON
2. Send it like it is by escaping all the quotes with slash.

1

```
 private static MyObject obj = MyObject.builder()
                                       .title("Title")
                                       .userId("1234")
                                       .build();


        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .and()
                .body(Gson.toJson(obj))
                .when()
                .post("/posts")
```

2

```
    private static String requestBody = "{\n" +
            "  \"title\": \"foo\",\n" +
            "  \"body\": \"bar\",\n" +
            "  \"userId\": \"1\" \n}";


        Response response = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Content-type", "application/json")
                .and()
                .body(requestBody)
                .when()
                .post("/posts")
```